# Why does OvO and OvR return the same result?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, roc, multiclass-classification

I'm using scikit-learn's roc_auc_score() function for a multiclass classification problem. With iris which has three labels (and another dataset), I'm getting the exact same output when I use one-vs-one and one-vs-rest. Does anyone know why this is the case? Here's my code:

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, stratify=y, random_state=0)
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0)
clf = clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = clf.predict_proba(X_test)
auc_ovr = roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred, average='macro', multi_class='ovr')
auc_ovo = roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred, average='macro', multi_class='ovo')
print(f'OVR: {auc_ovr}, OVO: {auc_ovo}')
```

The last line's output is:

```
OVR: 0.9833333333333334, OVO: 0.9833333333333334
```

Comment: Can you explain *why* you would expect them to be *different*?

Comment: In Iris's case the dataset is balanced (and to be honest I'm not that familiar with Iris). But in the data that I'm using for my project there is imbalance across classes; so with average='macro' they cannot be the same because OvR is sensitive to class imbalance and OvO is not.

Comment: That's a reason to expect they _needn't_ be the same, but not a reason to expect they _must be different_.  You might try playing around with `sklearn.datasets.make_classification` to generate more datasets to experiment with.

Comment: As for the specific case, I think iris is just too easy, too small, and too balanced to see a difference.